# Expose container ports to localhost using docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have a rails app where I am using `docker-compose` to start docker containers.

`$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d`

But I can't access my app on my server's ip address (i.e. `server's public ip address`:`port`). Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  database:
  app:
  search_conf:
services:
  pgsql:
    container_name: pgsql
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  sphinx:
    container_name: sphinx
    image: leodido/sphinxsearch:2.2.9
    hostname: sphinx
    command: searchd.sh
    links:
      - pgsql
    volumes:
      - app:/app
      - search_conf:/usr/local/etc/
  foobar:
    container_name: foobar
    env_file: .env.dev
    links:
      - pgsql
      - sphinx
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: rails s
    volumes:
      - app:/app
```

How do I access my app on my server's ip address?

Comment: I think that should work as is. Are you sure you don't have network filtering in the way?

Comment: @DanLowe I was setting this up on Alibaba Cloud service. Whenever I try the container's IP address on my mobile or on my laptop. It redirects me to 0.0.0.0:3000. Whereas if I try the `server's ip address`:`port`, then it shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You compose file seems okay so there are a few things that I would check in order to debug this:

- Have you tried running it locally? If it doesn't work locally server in the container may be listening on `127.0.0.1:3000` instead of `0.0.0.0:3000`.
- If it works locally, the case may be that you hosting denies inbound connections on port 3000 and it's not a problem with docker-compose but with your configuration?
- Have you logged into server and checked that containers are in fact running without any problems? (So they didn't die after deploy).
- Have you tried reaching the endpoint from your server? (So ssh into
  it and try accessing the app through localhost with curl or wget)
- Have you checked logs
  of the application? Maybe it's working after all but app is crashing
  or rejecting connections? Try with `docker-compose logs foobar | less`

I guess this is not really specific, but there is not much to go with tbh.